# Intent ACTION_CALL android

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I am trying to search for activities that have intent filters to be used for phone calls. This is what I was trying to do to get all available activities:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(callIntent, 0);
```

This causes the resolveInfo list to be null, which means no activity has been found to make a phone call.
Despite that if I use the following intent, the built in android app to make phone calls gets started:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 8888888888));
                        activity.startActivity(callIntent);
```

My ultimate goal is to use the telephone app, that is used in HTC ONE M8 as part of the CAR APP.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the line of       setdata to your intent like:

```
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 888888888));
```

then the complete code will be:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + 888888888));
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(callIntent, 0);
    Log.d("data", resolveInfo.size()+"");
```

Now you will found the number of available activities.

Comment: Thank you, addidng the line .setData(..) made the difference. Now I can see all activities that can be used for the phone call!

Comment: This only solved a part of my question. I am trying to use the Car App application of the HTC ONE M8. But probably if the developer of the application does not provide an intent and I do not know the package name, I won't be able to use the app's activity. Is my assumption right?